# Apache not accessable via network

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, centos6

I've set up CentOS 6.x on an old fujitsu server and want to use it as webserver. I can access apache via localhost and 127.0.0.1 and I can already access webmin via port localhost:10000 (whatever that's for ^^) BUT I can't access it via the server's ip adress and my laptop(via LAN over a router). What am I doing wrong? Is that a firewall problem or something?

CentOS is installed on ESXi virtualisation software but I think that shouldn't make any difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In centos 6.x iptables (a firewall) is enabled for default.

"service iptables stop" to stop iptables

If you want open some port on the firewall follow this guide http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-rhel-linux-open-port-using-iptables/

Comment: Thanks but I still can only access it via localhost and not from another pc in my lan...

Comment: ha, the command "service iptables stop" didn't work but your hint with the firewall was good! found the solution to disable it here: http://www.lifelinux.com/how-to-enabledisable-firewall-on-centos-redhat-fedora/